# Spin ImageView without losing height and width in android studio

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio, roulette-wheel-selection

i am developing a roulette game for learning while my friend ask me to make spinning wheel shape from circle to oval. after changing shape of ImageView to an oval and trying to rotate ,it's height and width are swapping according to each 90-degree rotation. while height and width should not change as i need, following are codes i am using and screenshot attached
thanks for your time .

***layout_main.xml***

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/iframe"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true">

   <ImageView
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="150dp"
       android:src="@drawable/wheel2min_300x300"
       android:scaleType="fitXY"
       android:id="@+id/wheel_image"
       android:layout_centerInParent="true"
       android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
       android:layout_marginTop="25dp"/>
   <ImageView
       android:layout_width="50dp"
       android:layout_height="40dp"
       android:src="@drawable/target_147x300"
       android:scaleType="fitXY"
       android:id="@+id/wheel_pointer"
       android:layout_centerInParent="true"
       android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"/>
</FrameLayout>
   <Button
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:text="press to spin"
       android:id="@+id/spin_button"
      android:layout_below="@id/iframe"
      android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
      android:layout_marginTop="15dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

***MainActivity.java***

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ImageView imageView;
    private Button button;
    int h,w;
    CountDownTimer countDownTimer;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        imageView = findViewById(R.id.wheel_image);
        button = findViewById(R.id.spin_button);
        h=imageView.getHeight();
        w = imageView.getWidth();
        Random random = new Random();

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {


                button.setEnabled(false);

                // reading random value between 10 to 30
                int spin = random.nextInt(20)+10;

                // since the wheel has 10 divisions, the
                // rotation should be a multiple of
                // 360/10 = 36 degrees
                spin = spin * 36;

                // timer for each degree movement
                countDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(spin*20,1) {
                    @Override
                    public void onTick(long l) {
                        // rotate the wheel
                        float rotation = imageView.getRotation() + 2;
                        imageView.setRotation(rotation);

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFinish() {
                        // enabling the button again
                       button.setEnabled(true);
                    }
                }.start();

            }
        });



    }
```

***UI i want even when rotation***

[image: screenshot]

Comment: After rethinking this and running some tests, I'm not sure that my suggestion of `RotateDrawable` is usable here. Sorry about that. The image in that setup would be scaled before rotation, which is backwards. I put together a couple of examples from those tests that I think have the effect that you're looking for: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1EE8NtM81V2TJGdVCz1XBbRqCMXDB7SB7/view?usp=share_link. Look like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/S26Od.gif.

Comment: @MikeM. thanks for your response, please post it as an answer so i can mark it as solution. that is what i actually need . i really appreciate your help, thank you again

Comment: No problem. Good to hear. I'm too lazy to put together answers these days, though, so please feel free to finish up this question however you like. Thanks for the offer. Glad I could help. Cheers!